# Eloquent Javascript 2nd. Chapter 4. Computing Correlation. Final Analysis - [Variable Recursion & in operator] Pt 2

Tags: javascript

I'm working through the end of the first example in Chapter 4 Eloquent Javascript. Here is the full piece of code (It's the last piece that I have questions regarding but I attached the first portion for reference).

```
var journal = [];

function addEntry(events, didITurnIntoASquirrel) {
  journal.push({
    events: events,
    squirrel: didITurnIntoASquirrel
  });

function phi(table) {
  return (table[3] * table[0] - table[2] * table[1]) /
    Math.sqrt((table[2] + table[3]) *
              (table[0] + table[1]) *
              (table[1] + table[3]) *
              (table[0] + table[2]));
}

function hasEvent(event, entry) {
  return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}

function tableFor(event, journal) {
  var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
    var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
    if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;
    if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
    table[index] += 1;
  }
  return table;
}

function gatherCorrelations(journal) {
  var phis = {};
  for (var entry = 0; entry < journal.length; entry++) {
    var events = journal[entry].events;
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var event = events[i];
      if (!(event in phis))
        phis[event] = phi(tableFor(event, journal));
    }
  }
  return phis;
}

var correlations = gatherCorrelations(JOURNAL);
console.log(correlations.pizza);
```

My questions are:

1. What is the purpose of the .events in

   `var events = journal[entry].events;`

Does it call on itself as a recursion? If so why? Couldn't we have just had journal[entry] and the function would run calling on the entry from the tableFor function? Does it call back to the AddEntry function (where the events variable was established) in an important way?

2. What is the purpose of `(!(event in phis))`.

I read it as : if event in phis is true then flip it to be not true and then trigger necessary phi calculation. Wouldn't it make more sense to eliminate the ! (does not equal) or that piece of code altogether? If we already have a for loop won't the function run on it's on until the max length of journal and stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var events = journal[entry].events;` you are getting the `events` object from the object at index `entry` in the array `journal` and assigning it to a temporary variable called `events`.

This is just done for convenience so you don't have to keep referring to `journal[entry].events`. For example, later on it has this line:

```
var event = events[i];
```

which would become:

```
var event = journal[entry].events[i];
```

Without the assignment to a temporary variable.

`if(!(event in phis))` it's testing to see if the object `phis` does not have a property with the name contained in the variable `event`. If the object doesn't already have that property, it adds it with the next line:

```
phis[event] = phi(tableFor(event, journal));
```

See [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Here's a very simple snippet of code to help understand the `in` operator:

```
var foo = {};
console.log("bar" in foo);    // logs "false" because foo doesn't have a "bar" property
foo.bar = 1;                  // or foo["bar"] = 1;
console.log("bar" in foo);    // logs "true" because foo now has a "bar" property
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the purpose of the .events in

   var events = journal[entry].events;

The purpose of this declaration conforms with 2 concepts of scripting convenience and economy.  Every level of an object depth adds to the overall recall time when called.  Certainly modern browsers have done much to flatten an objects variable stack, but if you think about it logically, any call to say object1.object2["Memeber3"].object4 has to go through 4 steps to get to the value itself.  Flattening the value to a local object is more economic.  Second, the readability (and therefore maintainability) of the code is enhanced in that you don't have the extra "journal[entry]." clogging up your expressions.  As a general rule of thumb, if you are going to use a member of an object more than once in a block, then you should create a local variable of that member.

---

2. What is the purpose of

   (!(event in phis)).

The purpose of this evaluation is to determine if a particular member(event) is NOT in the object(phis).  In this example, the next line creates that member if it is indeed missing.